# C# - XML Document Won't Save

Tags: c#, xml, save

```
document = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
document.CreateAttribute("EncryptionKey");
document.CreateAttribute("SaltKey");
document.CreateAttribute("VIKey");
document.CreateAttribute("EmailUsername");
document.CreateAttribute("EmailPassword");
document.AppendChild(docNode);
document.Save("Credentials.xml");
```

Apparently the root doesn't exist, even though I made one and applied it.

EDIT: What it should come out with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt5vU.jpg

Comment: What the desired output is, please specify

Comment: To create an XML file with the attributes I listed. It's there in the code.

Comment: That was extremely helpful

Comment: Please, provide an example of the desired output

Comment: ...

https://imgur.com/a/Crk3A

Comment: It's not a valid Xml as it doesn't have a root element

Comment: I thought the XML declaration was that. How do I make a root element?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this. With a root node named "Credentials"

```
private void CreateXml()
{
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode rootNode = document.CreateElement("Credentials");
    document.AppendChild(rootNode);

    rootNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("EncryptionKey"));
    rootNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("SaltKey"));
    rootNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("VIKey"));
    rootNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("EmailUsername"));
    rootNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("EmailPassword"));

    XmlNode declaration = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    document.InsertBefore(declaration, rootNode);

    document.Save("Credentials.xml");
}
```

**EDIT**: Added declaration

Comment: 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type.'

Using this code: https://imgur.com/a/9MeQ7

Comment: Works now. Thanks.